# how to install download-monitor on 15.10

Tags: downloads, monitor

i have 15.10 and want download-monitor as shown from https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/download-monitor/

it is not available.  How to make it available?

Comment: What issues are you having downloading it? Does the software center or apt-get give you errors?

Answer (score 0):

From this page https://launchpad.net/download-monitor :

> Download Monitor is no longer developed or supported. It has been
>   replaced by BitBudget: http://lazyteq.github.com/bitbudget/

That github link doesn’t work for me, but I searched on launchpad and it seems to have a page https://launchpad.net/bitbudget. You can download the source directly from there. Its also not available from the standard package repositories using apt-get

In short - that package doesn’t exist any more. Best to find an alternative, of which I am sure there are many.

Comment: Please name the replacement